# how to convert a dictionary's keys into an array sorted by the values to which those keys correspond in the dictionary

Tags: ios, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary. Its keys are strings and its values are NSDates. For example:

```
{ A : <jan 1>, B : <mar 1>, C : <feb 1> }
```

I want to create an array from the keys in the dictionary (A, B, & C), sorted by date. So I should end up with the following array:

```
[A, C, B]
```

How can I accomplish this?

**Bonus points**: With that sorted array, I could accomplish my end goal, but the sorted array would be just an intermediary; the most elegant solution wouldn't need it. What I really want to do is sort an array of objects, each of which has a property value corresponding to one of the *keys* in the dictionary. For example:

```
[obj1, obj2, obj3]
```

where

```
obj1.prop = A
obj2.prop = B
obj3.prop = C
```

I want to sort that array based on the date values of A, B, & C, referencing the dictionary. So my end goal in this scenario would be the following array:

```
[obj1, obj3, obj2]
```

Thanks!

Comment: You must have at least tried out writing some code... Post that as well..

Comment: @akashg I judiciously went with a clear question over flailing code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on David's answer, this will solve it all together:

```
NSDictionary* items = @{ @"A":date1, @"B":date2, @"C":date3 };
NSArray *objectsArray = @{ obj1, obj2, obj3 };
NSArray *sortedObjectsArray = [objectsArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSDate *date1 = [items objectForKey:obj1.prop];
    NSDate *date2 = [items objectForKey:obj2.prop];
    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
```

Comment: Not very nice to take somebody else's answer and incorporate it into your own.

Comment: in what way did I take your answer? Just because I used the same name for the dictionary? I had the solution in my head and just copied that line to avoid typing, but the answer was a different one.

Comment: there is a difference between building up on another answer while providing an improved solution and taking parts of another answer to improve your own. but maybe it was just an unfortunate coincidence and you just came up with the same idea - it's not that far fetched^^ in that case I appologize for complaining

Comment: Your answer "And this will solve it all together" implies that you're building on another answer.  The correct thing to do on SO is to explicitly attribute that you're expanding somebody else's answer.  Honestly, if you hadn't complained about mine, I wouldn't have bothered with yours.

Comment: that why I wrote the first line ;) but I've edited it to explicitly state it. But honestly this has become a far too long discussion for such a point. I was just a little pissed earlier, had a bad day. It was no big deal, feel free to add that part back to your answer if you want to :)

Answer (score 2):

The following will accomplish your first objective:

```
NSDictionary*   items = @{ @"A":@2, @"B":@1, @"C":@3};
keys = [[items allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [items[obj1] compare:items[obj2]];
}];
```

From that you should be able to extrapolate the answer to your other questions.

Comment: I didn't realize I was.  And it would be equally appropriate to say you did the same thing taking my answer.  But I've removed the "offending" bit.

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish your second question

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescrip = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"prop"
                                              ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescrips = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescrip];
NSArray *sortedArray = [originalArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescrips];
```